# QTextStream formatting issue

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, format, qtextstream

I am trying to use a `QTextStream` to format numerical output.  I've simplified my issue into a little test program to demonstrate my problem.  Following is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("testfile.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream out(&file);

        out.setFieldAlignment(QTextStream::AlignLeft);
        out.setFieldWidth(5);

        out << "1" << "A" << endl;
        out << "2" << "B" << endl;
        out << "3" << "C" << endl;
        out << "4" << "D" << endl;
        out << "5" << "E" << endl;
        out << "6" << "F" << endl;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is the output generated by the above program:

```
1    A    
    2    B    
    3    C    
    4    D    
    5    E    
    6    F
```

Notice the indentation on the bottom five lines?  That's my problem, is I don't want the indentation to start new lines.  I want every line to begin at column 0, and to write a value that is five columns wide (my field width) and for it to be left-justified.

I've tried playing around with the parameters for sometime without luck.  If I can get this to work in the little test program above, I think I can have success porting that change into my much larger program that writes a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of overcoming this is to use `qSetFieldWidth` before and after writing `endl`. Setting width to zero before writing `endl` and again setting to the previous value.

It will not change your code much because of the convenient `qSetFieldWidth` function which is equivalent to  `QTextStream::setFieldWidth` :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("testfile.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream out(&file);

        out.setFieldAlignment(QTextStream::AlignLeft);
        out.setFieldWidth(5);

        out << "1" << "A" << qSetFieldWidth(0) << endl <<qSetFieldWidth(5);
        out << "2" << "B" << qSetFieldWidth(0) << endl <<qSetFieldWidth(5);
        out << "3" << "C" << qSetFieldWidth(0) << endl <<qSetFieldWidth(5);
        out << "4" << "D" << qSetFieldWidth(0) << endl <<qSetFieldWidth(5);
        out << "5" << "E" << qSetFieldWidth(0) << endl <<qSetFieldWidth(5);
        out << "6" << "F" << qSetFieldWidth(0) << endl <<qSetFieldWidth(5);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Now the result is :

```
1    A    
2    B    
3    C    
4    D    
5    E    
6    F
```

Answer (score 2):

From `QTextStream::setFieldWidth` documentation:

> Note: The field width applies to every element appended to this stream after this function has been called (e.g., it also pads endl).

Clearly this is the cause of your issue: `endl` symbol is padded with 4 spaces just as any other character you put in the stream. A possible workaround is to set field width to 0 before adding endl and resetting field width after that, or to disable stream padding completely and rely on other ways of padding like `QString::leftJustified`.

Comment: I had seen that in the documentation, but I was hoping they would be a simpler solution than constantly setting and resetting the field width.  I can confirm that your method is a workaround.